# D3.js - Removing other bars except one

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using d3.js, I've created a bar chart whose bars transition in and can also transition out, when you click on one of the bars. What I'd like to have happen, however, is have all the bars transition out, EXCEPT for the one that I clicked on.

My transition-in is done via:

```js
bars
    .attr('height', 0)
    .attr('y', height)
    .style('fill-opacity', 1)
    .transition()
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return y(d);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return height - y(d);
    })
    .delay(function(d, i) {
      return i * delay;
    })
    .duration(duration)
    .ease(easing);
```

And my transition-out is specified using

```js
bars
  .transition()
  .attr('height', 0)
  .attr('y', height)
  .duration(300)
  .delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * delay;
  });
```

How do I modify this to transition out all other bars except for the one that was clicked on?

Comment: Why not formulate your code in terms of enter/update/exit, so that when a bar is clicked, you can `.data()` bind to a single-element array containing just that bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may employ [`selection.filter()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections#filter) to filter out the one bar, which received the click event and subsequently transition all the others.

```
bars.on("click", function() {
  var clicked = this;   // Remember which bar received the click

  bars
    .filter(function() {
      return this != clicked;  // Use a filter to select all other bars for the transition.
    })
    .transition()
    .attr('height', 0)
    .attr('y', height)
    .duration(300)
    .delay(function(d, i) {
      return i * delay;
    });
});
```

Given the sparse snippets you provided, this should work under any circumstances, although there might be more elegant or more efficient ways to achieve the same thing. As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978608/d3-js-removing-other-bars-except-one#comment63404797_37978608) by meetamit, one approach might involve the use of data bound to the elements. However, any more elaborate solution requires more insights in the rest of your code and the structure of your data.

Comment: Is there a reference I can use to learn about the approach you and meetamit are suggesting? I'd like to learn more about the "enter/update/exit" paradigm.

Comment: @codedawg82 Have a look at [*How Selections Work*](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/), [*Thinking with Joins*](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) and the series on the [*General Update Pattern*](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218). These should provide a good starting point to learn about D3's specific way of manipulating the DOM based on data.